# Como Rotacionar uma letra?

Tags: css, rotação, style

Estou tentando rotacionar uma letra de uma palavra, para deixa-la igual ao Logotipo da empresa.

Este seria o Logotipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui foi o código que tentei utilizar para rotacionar

```
<h1 class="text-center"><span style="color:blue;font-family:Gabriola;font-size:120px; "><b>E</b></span><span style="color:red;"><span style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);transform: rotate(-90deg);">B</span>yte</span></h1>
```

e então ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PS: É APENAS A LETRA B PARA DAR UMA GIRADINHA**

Comment: Se quiser uma referência extra do `rotate`, dê uma olhada no terceiro exemplo aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104671/70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 Transforms não funcionam em elementos inline, que no seu caso é um `span`.

O que você pode fazer é adicionar um `display: inline-block` no elemento que você deseja rotacionar.

Fiz a alteração aqui:

```
<h1 class="text-center"><span style="color:blue;font-family:Gabriola;font-size:120px;"><b>E</b></span><span style="color:red;"><span style="transform: rotate(-25deg); display: inline-block;">B</span>yte</span></h1>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara! era justamente o que eu precisava